# Identify first occurrence of an entry in a list, if certain criteria is met (EXCEL)

Tags: excel, formula

I have spent too much time trying to figure our the question imposed, in the title of this question, and am reaching out for some help.

I would like to output an entry of 1 for the first occurrence when criteria is equal to AR and output an entry of 1 for the first occurrence on a column when criteria is equal to SFR on a seperate column.

For example the columns I'd want in the following table are the columns titled `AR` and `SFR`

```
|Property Name  | product | company | AR | SFR |
|---------------|---------|---------|----|-----|
|orange grove   |    2    |   SFR   | 0  |  1  |
|orange grove   |    1    |   AR    | 1  |  0  |
|orange grove   |    6    |   AR    | 0  |  0  |
|garden court   |    2    |   SFR   | 0  |  1  |
|garden court   |    1    |   AR    | 1  |  0  |
|chimney sweeps |    6    |   AR    | 1  |  0  |
|chimney sweeps |    2    |   SFR   | 0  |  1  |
|chimney sweeps |    1    |   AR    | 0  |  0  |
|chimney sweeps |    4    |   SFR   | 0  |  0  |
|downing apts   |    2    |   SFR   | 0  |  1  |
|downing apts   |    1    |   SFR   | 0  |  0  |
|downing apts   |    6    |   AR    | 1  |  0  |
```

I tried implementing `countif` within my formula and only taking into consideration when my output is a result of 1, then nesting the formula for criteria "AR" or "SFR" with the result of my countif, if the criteria is satisfied, but the table isn't organized so that AR comes first in the table row and vice versa. Here is an example of my formula:

```
=IF(E2="AR", IF(COUNTIF($C$2:C2,C2)=1,1,""), "")
```

Sometimes I'll have instances where the company name occurs but the count isn't 1. Take for example `orange grove`. Orange grove's count would be 1, 2, 3 consecutively, for each +1 instance. If my count is 1 and `SFR`, my formula would output a 1 but if my criteria is `AR` and the count is not 1 (it's actually 2 or 3), I don't get a first occurrence output per my criteria of `AR`.

I saw there may be a way to utilize `sumproduct` but I am not familiar with it.

Could anyone please help. Anything would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would guanrantee you a result if you could `CONCATENATE` the Property Name and Company and then input the below mentioned formula into `AR` and `SFR` cells.

1. Insert a column and use `=CONCATENATE(A2," ",C2)` to merge Product
   Name and Company. It should give you result in space delimited
   format. For eg. orange grove SFR, chimney sweeps AR, etc.
2. Enter this formula in Cell E2 which belongs under `AR` column: `=IF(TRIM(RIGHT($D2,3))=E$1,IF(OR(COUNTIF($D:$D,$D2)=1,MATCH($D2,$D:$D,0)>=ROW($D2)),1,0),0)`
3. Drag the formula left onto Cell F2 to apply to `SFR` column and then to the bottom of each columns to apply for all records/rows.

In the end you will have the following result as expected:

**Table:**

```
R/C   A               B         C        D                    E     F

01    Property Name   product   company  Merged PN + C        AR    SFR
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
02    orange grove    2         SFR      orange grove SFR     0     1
03    orange grove    1         AR       orange grove AR      1     0
04    orange grove    6         AR       orange grove AR      0     0
05    garden court    2         SFR      garden court SFR     0     1
06    garden court    1         AR       garden court AR      1     0
07    chimney sweeps  6         AR       chimney sweeps AR    1     0
08    chimney sweeps  2         SFR      chimney sweeps SFR   0     1
09    chimney sweeps  1         AR       chimney sweeps AR    0     0
10    chimney sweeps  4         SFR      chimney sweeps SFR   0     0
11    downing apts    2         SFR      downing apts SFR     0     1
12    downing apts    1         SFR      downing apts SFR     0     0
13    downing apts    6         AR       downing apts AR      1     0
```

**Explanation:**

1. We merged Product Name & Company to identify unique records.
2. Then we created a condition to check for last 3 characters to match our column name: `=IF(TRIM(RIGHT($D2,3))=E$1`
3. If the above condition is true which means that we are in the correct Company column, we can now proceed to check if the Product Name instance is first or not. If not, then we are in the wrong column so just print 0.
4. As you mentioned there can be either a unique combination or multiple combinations of Product Name & Company. Therefore there are 2 conditions:
    a. When combination is unique i.e. count is equal to 1: `COUNTIF($D:$D,$D2)=1`
    b. When combination is duplicate but row number of first instance is less than equal to current row number: `MATCH($D4,$D:$D,0)>=ROW($D4)`
5. If either of the above 2 conditions are TRUE then the record is first instance and hence print 1, else it is not and hence print 0.

Hope it helped.

Comment: @aurora Please accept the correct answer and close the question if it solved the issue.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan, thank you so much for the help and explanation! The excel formula helped out and it does exactly what I needed it too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Column D and E are where your AR and SFR columns are respectively, try:

Table Structure:

```
    AR  SFR
AR  1   0
AR  0   0
AR  0   0
AR  0   0
AR  0   0
SFR 0   1
```

Cell D2 Would be (assuming AR is your column Header for column D)

```
=IF(C2=D1,1,0)
```

E2 Would be:

```
=IF(C2=E1,1,0)
```

For D3, then drag down for each cell in column D

```
=IF(SUM(D$2:D2)=0,IF($C3=D$1,1,0),0)
```

For E3, then drag down for each cell in column E

```
IF(SUM(E$2:E2)=0,IF($C3=E$1,1,0),0)
```

Thanks!

Ryan

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to read the question again. The solution needed is not first instance of just Company, but a combination of Product Name & Company.